# After Ajax request added self-closing tag <a>

Tags: jquery, ajax, hyperlink

The problem in getting the page content, according to the normal content should be to normal link, because In response, they are normal, but when you insert the right content div is removed links.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
{
var a=$('.glavnoe',data).eq(n);
$('.glavnoe').eq(n).html(a);
}
});
```

n - is position of className tag

The result before ajax is

```
<a href="/xxx/xxx/xx/xx/xxxxx/"><img src="http://xxxx.jpg" /><br>
<h4>Something</h4></a>
```

result after ajax is

```
<a href="/xxx/xxx/xx/xx/xxxxx/"></a><img src="http://xxxx.jpg" /><br>
<h4>Something</h4>
```

You see, before requesting a normal tag, but after the tag is closed immediately.
What are the possible solutions to this problem?

UPD1:
Problem is in slash on end of the links, if somehow remove this slash problem will be solved, but how ???

Comment: How does `data` look like? Which element has class `glavnoe`? Probably more html will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for jQuery easily can not solve this problem. Wrote at javascript xmlhttp request with the parser on iframe, there is no such problem appeared.